# How to pass hidden field in table and return the value in jquery on tr click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html

```
 <table id="result" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td >1</td>
         <td  >2</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="sDiv">
      <c:forEach items="${transactionList}" var="transactionInfo" varStatus="transactionIndex">
         <tr class="cursor-pointer" >
            <td >${transactionIndex.index + 1}</td>
            <td >${transactionInfo.desc}</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="${transactionInfo.uniqueId.Id}"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="${transactionInfo.uniqueId.value}"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="${transactionInfo.uniqueId.time}"/>
         </tr>
      </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

where transactionList is,

```
 [{
        "desc": "",
        "unidueId": {
            "id": "",
            "value": "",
            "time": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "desc": "",
        "unidueId": {
            "id": "",
            "value": "",
            "time": ""
        }
    }
 ]
```

This is the row click function, Im using data table to intialize. But intial load im using the normal table data.
So DataTable() is working as expected and Im getting the row data . Row data contains only td values not the hidden field.

```
 $('#result tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = $('#result').DataTable().row( this ).data();
        console.log("data :"+JSON.stringify(data));
    } );
```

Here how can I pass the hidden data from jsp to javascript in table. Fetch data from jquery on click function.

Prefered solution

Can I pass whole json as one field ?

Comment: you didn't add name attribute in hidden fields

Comment: ok how will I fetch by name ? since its not displaying any of those hidden value in console

Comment: answer added and working fiddle also added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.
[Working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jdreyv65/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="result" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td >1</td>
         <td  >2</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="sDiv">
     
         <tr class="cursor-pointer" >
            <td >${transactionIndex.index + 1}</td>
            <td >${transactionInfo.desc}</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="100"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="date" value="2021-08-25"/>
         </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
var dataval= [];
$('#result tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = {};
    data.id= $(this).closest("tr").find('[name="id"]').val();
    data.value= $(this).closest("tr").find('[name="value"]').val();
    data.date= $(this).closest("tr").find('[name="date"]').val();
    dataval.push(data);

    console.log("data :"+JSON.stringify(dataval));
});
```